# Using Git to merge a branch onto two other branches that are not identical

Tags: git, git-merge, branching-and-merging, branching-strategy

I have two branches, `ServerA` and `ServerB`. The code in both is nearly the same, but not identical. `ServerB` branched off of `ServerA` in the past. I want to create a new `dev` branch with code changes that will be merged into both of the server branches.

I could create `dev` by branching `ServerA`, but I don't want ServerA's differences to go to `ServerB` or vice versa.

Or I could create a separate `devA` and `devB` branches, but then changes common to both would have to be done twice, once in each dev branch.

Is there a way to create a single `dev` branch that I can merge into both server branches, that also allows me to continue to make server specific changes on each of the server branches?

I have tried merging, maybe an orphan branch or rebasing the new branch?

Comment: Are the 2 branches related? (As in, they share some ancestors). If they are _not_ related, is the layout of the name-space similar? (Same directories/files, even if there are differences).

Comment: If I understand correctly, and if the answer to @eftshift0's question is they do share ancestors, then  you could make your branch from the merge-base of the two server branches, e.g. `git switch -c new-branch $(git merge-base ServerA ServerB)`

Comment: _or_ even from the tip of one of the branches and then rebase `--onto` the other branch. But the technique to use depends on the answers.

Comment: Yes, they all they all come from ServerA originally.

Comment: Is the premise stated at the top of my answer correct? If so, I'd like to update your question so that it is easier to understand and more easily found by people in a similar situation.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to retroactively implement a "master" or "main" branch that contains all the common code, and have your "server" branches be branches off of it containing server-specific code.

Since `ServerA` was the original branch, it *was* the master branch up until you created `ServerB`. So that's where we'll start:

0. Back up your repo in case this process goes wrong somewhere.
1. Find the commit in the commit history where `ServerB` branches off from `ServerA`.
2. Create a new `master` branch at this point:

```bash
git branch master <SHA-1 or other ref for last common commit>
```

3. Incorporate changes common to both server branches into `master`. You can do this a number of ways:

   - Manually cherry-pick commits from `ServerA` that have equivalent commits on `ServerB`. Use this method if you want recreate the history of common changes in `master`. If the commit cherry-picked from `ServerA` also includes changes specific to `ServerA`, you can use `git cherry-pick -n` to give you a chance to remove those specifics, or you can use `git commit --amend` to fix them after each cherry-pick.

     > This option will recreate your original commit history in `master`. But the longer your commit history since "the split", the longer this will take. It may or may not be worth it to you.
   - Use your IDE or Git GUI frontend to do a diff between `ServerA` and `master`, then use the GUI to copy/merge individual changes into `master` that belong in `master`. Commit those changes into `master`.

     > This option will result in all your common changes since the fork point to be represented in `master` as a single commit.
   - Copy the latest state from `ServerA` into the worktree for `master`, remove all the `ServerA` specific stuff, and then commit this to `master`:

     1. `git checkout master`
     2. `git checkout master -- .` to update the state of your worktree to the head of master without switching branches
     3. `git add -p` to selectively add only the common changes to the index.
     4. `git commit` perhaps with a message stating that the commit includes all common changes since the ServerA/ServerB split.

     > This option will result in all your common changes since the fork point to be represented in `master` as a single commit.
4. Make the git history reflect the fact that all of the changes in the `master` branch have already been made in the server branches. Here are two ways:

   - Merge `master` into both server branches. If you did the previous steps accurately, you can safely tell git to resolve all conflicts by accepting what's already in the server branch:

     ```bash
     git checkout ServerA
     git merge -s ours master
     ```

     Since all the changes in `master` should already be in each of the server branches, it should be an empty commit, even with the conflict resolution above.
   - Rebase both server branches onto `master`. Do this if this is also what you place to do for the server branches going forward. If not, do the `merge` described above.
5. Confirm that the final state of each branch is right.

   - Diff the head of `ServerA` with its last commit before this process. It should be an empty diff. Do the same for `ServerB`.
   - Diff each server branch with `master`. You should see nothing in the diff that should be common to both servers.
6. Have a  or some .